# Software documentation: Where to put the class diagram: in the functional or design specifications

Tags: documentation, uml, class-diagram

I am writing the documentation of a software I have to develop.
I am respecting the V model:

http://sqa.fyicenter.com/FAQ/Software-Development-Models/models_1.JPG

My question is: where should I use the UML class diagram, in the functional spec or in design spec?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relation between the classes and the detail of the properties/methods inside those has nothing to do with WHAT the system is going to do, btu with HOW the system is going to do its job.
For this reason I'd put the UML class diagram in the design spec.

Moreover I usually won't put in design spec the entire class diagram, but also some part of it (if any) focused on particular topics (subtasks of the entire system).
I primarly use class diagram (and sequence diagram of course) for designing the application to make my mind clearly see the solution, but not for documenting it: the class diagram could (and will) often change from my first though, mainly due to refactoring.

Answer (score 2):

Don't disagree with the logic of other answers.  Here's another perspective though which may or may not be relevant.

If your class diagram models the problem domain (per e.g. [Domain-Driven Design](http://domaindrivendesign.org/resources/what_is_ddd)) then it can have a more fundamental purpose in defining the language of the problem domain ("ubiquitous language" in DDD terms).

So rather than being a (software) design artefact, it's actually more of a formalised glossary.  As such it defines the terms used in the functional spec.

Take the example of an online shopping system.  Your functional requirements will likely talk about 'buying a product', 'placing an item in the shopping basket', 'checking out' and such like.  Those terms - product, item, shopping basket - are implicitly defined.  But what about the rules that relate them?  For example, how many products can be in a shopping basket at once?  If you want to check out, must all items be paid for with a single payment?  Or can they be split?

Those sorts of rules can be formalised on a class diagram - and so it can be a very useful component of the functional requirements.

Whether or not it's applicable to you will depend on (a) the content of your class diagram, and (b) whether you & your requirements stakeholders will benefit from the clarity in rules & terminology it can bring.

As I said: another perspective.

hth.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that this is more a design specification thing. In the functional specification you want to think about what the software has to do and in the design specification you can start drafting some UML as well as mockups of the user interface of your code.

Hope that it helps